# JSON and Javascript - Can't pull nested data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api

OK, so i'm trying to loop over and pull "title" out of an API using javascript, API looks like this in console:

```
Object {status: "ok", data: Array[28]}
data:Array[28]
    0:Object    
        age_restricted:true
        always_on_menu:false
        box_limit:"2"
        id:"1907b434-f71d-11e5-887e-02787aad01f3"
        is_for_sale:true
        is_vatable:true
        list_price:"7.95"
        sku:"AP-ACH-WIN-WHI-06-P"
        title:" Camino Real Blanco Rioja"
```

Javascript as follows:

```
$.getJSON("URL", callbackData);

function callbackData(data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        var obj = data[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
             if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            document.write(JSON.stringify(prop));
        }
    }
}
}
```

But all I get is the Key so in this case the 0 come out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this?

```
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj[prop]));
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I had been looking at that for an hour thinking what on earth have I missed, i knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Data is an array, so the proper way to iterate through it is with forEach. Anyway, the value that you want to get is `obj[prop]`.

```
function callbackData(data) {
    data.forEach(function(obj) {
        for (var prop in obj) {
             if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                 document.write(JSON.stringify(obj[prop]));
             }
        }
    });
}
```